# How do you reuse the same openapi.yaml file for production and development

Tags: swagger, openapi, google-cloud-endpoints

We are using a GitOps model for deploying our software. Everything in `dev` branch goes to the dev environment and everything in `main` gets deployed to production. All good and fine except that we use Google Cloud Endpoints that rely in the `host` parameter of the `openapi.yaml`. There is only room for a single value so we have to remember to change it for each deployment not allowing us to do a fully automated deploy.

How do you manage the same `openapi.yaml` definition when using Google Cloud Endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one example given in the official documentation, see if it helps your use-case.

1. [Basic structure of an OpenAPI document](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-overview#basic_structure_of_an_openapi_document), notice how the "host" is parameterized with "**YOUR-PROJECT-ID**.appspot.com"
2. [Deploying the Endpoints configuration](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstart-endpoints#deploying_the_endpoints_configuration), using the provided script "./deploy_api.sh"
3. [Source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-quickstart/blob/master/scripts/deploy_api.sh) for deploy_api.sh

One common solution for different environments properties management is to create different build profiles, and create different environment specific properties files like openapi_dev.yaml, openapi_qa.yaml, openapi_prod.yaml, and supply the one based on the profile(dev/qa/prod) being used. Refer [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html) for more details.

Another way documented at [GitOps-style continuous delivery with Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/gitops-cloud-build), where a multi branch, multi-repository approach is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Under the FAQ section in  [Swagger OpenAPI guide](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/api-host-and-base-path/), it is clearly mentioned that, we can specify multiple hosts, e.g. development, test and production but for OpenAPI 3.0. OpenAPI2.0 supports only one host per API specification (or two if you count HTTP and HTTPS as different hosts). A possible way to target multiple hosts is to omit the host and schemes from your specification and serve it from each host. In this case, each copy of the specification will target the corresponding host.

As per [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-overview) Cloud Endpoints  currently support OpenAPI version 2.0. A feature request  has been filed for support of version 3.0 but there have been no releases. You can follow for the updates [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78271318).

Comment: Yes this is the situation I have now. By asking the question I was hoping someone finding a workaround for the combination Swagger 2.0 + Google Cloud Endpoints with different hosts for dev and prod.

Comment: I think its not possible any other way unless Swagger 3.0 is available on Endpoints.